# How can I assign .(for instance) number to second dimention array by using 'for each'

Tags: java

my teacher has asked to assign numbers to the second dimension of an array by using 'for each'. I tried to do it with the following code but it does not work:

```
int[][] Square = new int[5][5];

for(int row : Square[])

         for(int col : Square[][])

               -----
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
for ( int[] row : Square ) {
  for ( int col : row ) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through a two-dimensional array of ints gives you an one-dimensional array of int.
Looping through the one-dimensional array will give you an int.

```
for (int row[] : Square) {
    for(int col : row) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you intended was

```
int[][] square = new int[5][5];
for(int[] row : square)
     for(int col : row)
```

however this is often not very useful as you need to know the index as well.

```
int[][] square = new int[5][5];
for(int row=0; row < square.length; row++) {
     for(int col=0; col < square[row].length; col++) {
         int i = square[row][col];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is labelled as homework, I won't give you the whole answer.

However if you want to get the size of the arrays, you need to get the *length* of the relevant arrays e.g

```
Square.length
```

to get the length of the array of arrays, and

```
Square[x].length
```

to get the length of array `x`. Note that this gives you the appropriate index into the array, which may be of use. You can iterate through without that using:

```
for (int[] row : Square) {
  ...
```

etc. which doesn't give you the index. Check out the [Oracle nuts-and-bolts section on the for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more information.

(as an aside, I'd rename the variable to `square`, not `Square`. It's Java convention to name *types* of classes with an initial capital letter)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
int[][] Square = new int[5][5];
for(int[] row : Square) {
  for(int col : row) {
    System.out.println("Col = " + col);
  }
}
```

See http://javafiddle.net/xfMLMy